# How do I reset a list iterator in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

For example, in C++ I could do the following :-

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if(...){              //some condition
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

This will effectively reset the loop, i.e. start the loop over without introducing a second loop

For Python -

```
for x in a: # 'a' is a list
    if someCondition == True:
        # do something
```

Basically during the course of the loop the length of 'a' might change. So every time the length of 'a' changes, I want to start the loop over. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You'll likely need to use a `while` loop, or recursion.

Comment: Are values in the list being changed as you loop through them; are you just appending values to the end or inserting values into the list?

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge: Based on some condition, I'm appending values to the list. So every time I append a value, I want the loop to start over

Comment: @miradulo: But for that I'll need a variable to keep track of the length of my list. Is there no other way to do it?

Answer (score 9):

You could define your own iterator that can be rewound:

```
class ListIterator:
    def __init__(self, ls):
        self.ls = ls
        self.idx = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def rewind(self):
        self.idx = 0
    def __next__(self):
        try:
            return self.ls[self.idx]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        finally:
            self.idx += 1
```

Use it like this:

```
li = ListIterator([1,2,3,4,5,6])
for element in li:
    ... # do something
    if some_condition:
        li.rewind()
```

Answer (score 4):

Not using `for`, but doing by hand with a `while` loop:

```
n = len(a)
i = 0
while i < n:
  ...
  if someCondition:
    n = len(a)
    i = 0
    continue
  i+=1
```

edit - if you're just appending to the end, do you really need to start over? You can just move the finish line further, by comparing `i` to `len(a)` directly, or calling `n=len(a)` in your loop