# How can I supress Error messages in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, iterator

So I'm trying to make a program to delete all duplicate Letters from a given String. The code is basically a selfmade iterator, that I got from another post here: [How do I reset a list iterator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427501/how-do-i-reset-a-list-iterator-in-python)

```
string = "NNEEXXxxTTGGEENNCCOODDEERR"

class rmvDuplicates:

def __init__(self, list, newString):
    self.newString = newString
    self.list = list
    self.idx = 0
    self.content = list[self.idx]

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def get_content(self, content):
    return content

def get_index(self):
    return self.idx

def get_content_next(self, content):
    try:
        self.idx += 1
        return self.content
    finally:
        self.idx -= 1

def remove(self, elem):
    del self.list[self.idx]
    return

def rewind(self):
    self.idx = 0

def __next__(self):
    try:
        return self.list[self.idx]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    finally:
        self.idx += 1
        self.content = self.list[self.idx]  

new_String = []

li = rmvDuplicates(list(string), new_String)

for elem in li:
    if li.get_content(elem) == li.get_content_next(elem):
        print(li.get_content(elem))
        li.remove(elem)
        print(li.list)

print("Hello")
```

*Note: The `print("Hello")` is just for testing purposes*

I modified it a bit to match my needing and it works just fine, until it reaches the point of the `IndexError`.

```
def __next__(self):
    try:
        return self.list[self.idx]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    finally:
        self.idx += 1
        self.content = self.list[self.idx]
```

I already tried to figure that out myself, using the Except-Block with the pass method.

But still, the program displays this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rmv_dplc_cls.py", line 49, in <module>
    for elem in li:
  File "rmv_dplc_cls.py", line 42, in __next__
    self.content = self.list[self.idx]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone here know how to fix this, so the program keeps on running and doesn't abort.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use the same index again for which you have just determined that it is out of range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `__next__` method to:

```
def __next__(self): 
    try: 
        value = self.list[self.idx]
        self.idx += 1
    except IndexError:
        self.idx = 0
        value = self.list[self.idx]
    finally:
        return value
```

Explanation:

If your try clause fails, it means that `self.list[self.idx]` accesses an element which is outside of your list range, rhus raising the `IndexError`. That being the case, trying to access the same `self.list[self.idx]` will result in another `IndexError` this time outside from the try clause.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @jfaccioni. Your suggestion was very  helpful. It didn't quite qork for me, so I modified it a bit, like this:

```
def __next__(self):
    try:
        value = self.list[self.idx]
        self.idx += 1
        self.content = self.list[self.idx]
    except IndexError:
        value = self.list[self.idx]
    finally:
        if self.idx == len(self.list):
            raise StopIteration
        return value
```

I needed the  `self.content` for my function to work.

Thanks for your help.